# DVD : no medium found on /dev/sr0 when there is a DVD

Tags: 14.04, vlc, dvd, cd

I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and playing DVD's.

After installing 14.04 I came to the conclusion that I can not play any DVD's. DVD's cannot even be opened as they are not seen by Ubuntu.

The data I have until now:

- In the install of 13.10 this was no problem, so this excludes a hardware problem
- It's on 2 installs on 2 different computers.
- It concerns a Ubuntu and Lubuntu install
- The different libdvd libraries are installed:

  - libdvdread4 : version 4.2.1-2ubuntu1
  - libdvdnav4  : version 4.2.1-3
  - libdvdcss2  : version 1.2.13-0
  - ubuntu-restricted-extras : version 60
  - acidrip : version 0.14-0.2ubuntu7
- The dvd is found on `/dev/sr0`
- `eject /dev/sr0` does work like a charm
- `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /tmp/dvd` makes DVD to in but doesn't mount
- The dvd is found on `/dev/sr0`
- `lshw` on cdrom gives the DVD player with the `<status=nodisc>` when there is a dvd in it!
- playing a CD is no problem
- `ls -l /dev/sr0` gives :

  > brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 aug  9 20:20 /dev/sr0

  - I am in group cdrom
- vlc doesn't work as doesn't acidrip for that matter or mplayer
- changing regions doesn't work as the computer thinks there's no disc.
- vlc doesn't have problems with encyption (region) but just can't open `/dev/sr0`
- when using vlc as root it gives the same error, so it won't be a rights problem

`vlc -vvv /dev/sr0` gives a lot and this:

```
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.1
libdvdread: Could not open /dev/sr0 with libdvdcss.
libdvdread: Can't open /dev/sr0 for reading
libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
[0x7f1d18000e78] dvdnav demux warning: cannot open DVD (/dev/sr0)
```

So now I am stuck with two installs of Ubuntu 14.04 which don't play any DVD's. Can somebody help and/or ask some questions which lead me to an answer?

Comment: What does `lsblk` say when there is a disk in the device? `udisks --mount /dev/sr0` / `udisks --unmount /dev/sr0` / `udisks --eject /dev/sr0` ?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

Comment: I installed udisks and behavior on my Lubuntu install is somewhat flaky. What I found further : inserting a data DVD poses no problem, booting ubuntu from USB gives no problem regarding vlc and play back.

Comment: lsblk gives `sr0                            11:0    1     8G  0 rom `

Comment: udisks --mount /dev/sr0 gives a time-out and hogs the computer.

Comment: However after startup Lubuntu and inserting a disk starts the LXDE DVD-starter (what to do with DVD?)

Comment: Editing /etc/fstab file solved my problem. Details in: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1891405

Comment: For ubuntu 15 and above, see instead: `https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/script-install-css-sh-is-away/3372` as this shell script will not be availble.

Answer (score 4):

Try cleaning your DVD drive optical head. I had some flaky DVD recognition, similar symptoms, which got much better after cleaning the laser lens.

Comment: Who would think... I also had this problem :D

Comment: lol.. Mau its true.. Just cleaned with my shaving brush.. :)

Comment: Hmmm, it read the next DVD I put in it, which makes me think this isn't the issue in my instance, but other than a shaving brush, how do you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try running `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh` ?

It is a " shell script to install libdvdcss under Debian GNU Linux, many DVDs use css for encryption.  To play these discs, a special library is needed to decode them, libdvdcss.  Due to legal problems, Debian and most Linux distibutions cannot distribute libdvdcss "

This script will also install VLC if necessary

I do read that you have libdvdcss2 installed already, but in my experience I had to run this script before I could play DVD's.

Comment: According to the question, libdvdcss2 is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Also, be sure that your user is in the `cdrom` group.

> This right is gained by adding the user to the "cdrom" group.
>
> The "cdrom" group owns the CD-ROM devices in /dev.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges#Use_CD-ROM_drives

Answer (score 0):

For 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get purge libdvd-pkg
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

If you still can't get it to play, try borrowing a USB DVD player from somewhere. My new PC came with such a lame no-name DVD drive, it wouldn't play anything.