# New PC supplied with cheap no-name DVD drive that won't play

Tags: 18.04, dvd

This question [DVD : no medium found on /dev/sr0 when there is a DVD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509124/dvd-no-medium-found-on-dev-sr0-when-there-is-a-dvd) describes the problem perfectly.

I have libdvdcss2 installed:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ apt-cache show libdvdcss2
Package: libdvdcss2
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 58
Maintainer: Dmitry Smirnov <onlyjob@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: libdvdcss
Version: 1.4.2-1~local
Replaces: libdvdcss-dev (<= 0.0.3-3), libdvdcss0 (<= 1.0.0-0.0), libdvdcss2-dev (<= 1.2.10-0.0)
Provides: libdvdcss
Depends: libdvd-pkg, libc6 (>= 2.7)
Description: library for accessing encrypted DVDs
 libdvdcss is a library for accessing and unscrambling DVDs encrypted
 with the Content Scramble System (CSS).
 libdvdcss is part of the VideoLAN project.
 .
 This package provides runtime libraries.
Description-md5: b4dc268f8bf25f4d6f75457d311f45f1
Homepage: https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html

adam@gondolin:~$
```

but still I couldn't play anything on my new PC.

I then got the bright idea to plug in a USB DVD drive, and that played everything.

So is there anything I can do to get my cheap no-name DVD drive to work?

**Update - just realised there's some bad errors in syslog**

```
May  5 21:52:29 localhost kernel: [119099.113332] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
May  5 21:52:29 localhost kernel: [119099.113339] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#8 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
May  5 21:52:29 localhost kernel: [119099.113346] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#8 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
May  5 21:52:29 localhost kernel: [119099.113352] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#8 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 20 67 00 00 00 40 00
May  5 21:52:29 localhost kernel: [119099.113356] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 8494080
May  5 21:52:29 localhost kernel: [119099.141560] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
May  5 21:52:29 localhost kernel: [119099.141567] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#9 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
May  5 21:52:29 localhost kernel: [119099.141573] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#9 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
May  5 21:52:29 localhost kernel: [119099.141579] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#9 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 20 67 00 00 00 02 00
May  5 21:52:29 localhost kernel: [119099.141583] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 8494080
May  5 21:52:29 localhost kernel: [119099.141592] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 1061760, async page read
```

This is the complaint from VLC:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ vlc /dev/sr0
VLC media player 3.0.3 Vetinari (revision 3.0.3-1-0-gc2bb759264)
[000056005060f570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.0
libdvdread: Could not open /dev/sr0 with libdvdcss.
libdvdread: Can't open /dev/sr0 for reading
libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.0
libdvdread: Could not open /dev/sr0 with libdvdcss.
libdvdread: Can't open /dev/sr0 for reading
libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
[00007f2cb00015a0] filesystem stream error: read error: Input/output error
[00007f2cb0001830] cache_read stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
[00007f2cb0017f90] mjpeg demux error: cannot peek
```

Comment: Is it a DVD-Video? If so, is it of the region set for the first drive you tried?

Comment: Yes, video. I'd be surprised if the vendor had supplied a DVD drive for a different region! I just tried `regionset` to try to read the region from it but it demands a DVD be in the drive :( The only thing I can do with the drive is `eject /dev/sr0`